# Can this be solved using divergence theorem? $\iint_{S^+} dydz + dzdx +dxdy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

$$
  \iint_{S^+}   \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}z
              + \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}x
              + \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
$$
Bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=0$. If I use the divergence theorem (Gauss-Ostrogradsky) I get zero. But ifI solve this using the regular method I get $\pi$. The area is closed, it is a circle. Why can’t I use the divergence theorem here?

Comment: How are you using divergence theorem?

Comment: $P=0,Q=0,R=0$ so the partial derivatives are also 0.

Comment: In the divergence theorem shouldn't the surface surround a non-zero volume? While the volume of $x^2+y^2= 1$ and $z=0$ is zero

Comment: I dont know that

Comment: $x^2+y^2=1, \ z=0$ is just a circle, not a surface. Should it be $x^2+y^2 \leq 1,\ z=0$?

Comment: @md2perpe yes, i should have writen bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Over what volume do you integrate the divergence, and do you take that value as the answer when you get zero?

Comment: @md2perpe Oh  i see there is no volume MostafaAyaz was right.  This problem was actually a line integral that was converted to a surface integral via Stokes theorem.